# Get random regions from single sites

Tags: python, random, bioinformatics

I have a file (FileA) with n number of genomic regions in the following format:

```
Chromosome    Start    End  Length    Number  
chr1     100    400    300    6...
```

I have another (much larger) FileB (control dataset) containing single sites in the following format:

```
Chromosome    Site    
chr1    105
chr1    110...
```

from which I'd like to choose random entries based on the first dataset. 
So for each region in in the first file I'd get a random region from the second dataset with the same length and number but at a random location.

ex:

```
Chromosome    Start    End  Length    Number  
chr5     350    650    300    6...
```

So far what I have is:

```
List = []
NewList = []
LineCount = 0

for Line in FileB:
    if LineCount == 0:
        OutFile.write(Line)
    else:
        List.append(Line)
    LineCount +=1


for Line in FileA:
    Chr, Start, End, Len, Entries = Line.strip("\n").split("\t")[:5]
    RandomStart = random.sample(List, 1)
    ## here I need to find a way to keep adding sequential lines to a NewList till the last site minus the first site is near the Len
    ## then I need to convert this new list into the format Chr, Start, End, Lenght, Number and write out and then clear NewList
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far?

Comment: How can you find a region in the second dataset of the same length and number, if the second dataset only contains sites (without length and number)? Or do you want to take a region from the first set, then take a random site from the second and turn it into a region starting at the site of the second with length and number of the first?

Comment: What is a "location" and where is that information in your data sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved the problem and am posting the main portions of my code:

```
import random

def get_regions(i, Chr, Start, End, Len):
    n = EndN = 0
    while 0 < (End - Start) <= int(Len)+15:
        End = int(Dict[i+1].split("\t")[2])
        EndN = int(Dict[i].split("\t")[2])
        i +=1
        n +=1
    if int(Len)-15 <= (EndN - Start) <= int(Len)+15:
        OutFile.write(Chr + '\t'+str(Start)+ '\t'+str(EndN) +'\t'+ str(n) +'\t'+str(int(EndN)-int(Start))+ '\n')
        NewList =[]
    else:
        Chr, Start, End, i = get_random(Keys)

def get_random(Keys):
    i = random.sample(Keys, 1)[0]
    Chr = Dict[i].split('\t')[0]
    Start = int(Dict[i].split('\t')[1])
    End = int(Dict[i+10].split('\t')[2])
    get_regions(i, Chr, Start, End, Len)
    return Chr, Start, End, i


InFile = open(FileB, 'r')
OutFile = open(OutFile, 'w')
Dict = {}
LineCount = 0

for Line in InFile:
    if LineCount > 0:
        Dict[LineCount-1] = Line
    LineCount +=1


LineCount = 0
DiffFile = open(FileA, "r")
for Line in DiffFile:
    if LineCount ==0:
        Header = Line
        OutFile.write(Header)
    else:
        Entries, Len = Line.strip("\n").split("\t")[3:5]
        Keys = Dict.keys()
        Chr, Start, End, i = get_random(Keys)
    LineCount +=1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all regions in B with the same length and number as a region in A (and assuming A and B are tsv files), you might be able to do something like this:

```
fileA = open(pathToFileA).read()
fileB = open(pathToFileB).read()

out = open("foundMatches.tsv", "w")

splitA = FileA.split("\n")
splitB = FileB.split("\n")

For genomicRegion in SplitA:
    splitRegionsA = genomicRegions.split("\t")
    chromosomeA = splitRegionsA[0]
    startA = splitRegionsA[1]
    endA = splitRegionsA[2]
    lengthA = splitRegionsA[3]
    numberA = splitRegionsA[4]

    for genomicRegionB in SplitB:
        splitRegionsB = genomicRegionsB.split("\t")
        chromosomeB = splitRegionsB[0]
        startB = splitRegionsB[1]
        endB = splitRegionsB[2]
        lengthB = splitRegionsB[3]
        numberB = splitRegionsB[4]

        if lengthA == lengthB:
            if numberA == numberB:
                out.write(str(chromosomeA) + "\t" + str(startA) + "\t" + str(endA) + "\t" + str(lengthA) + "\t" + str(numberA) + "\t" + str(chromosomeB) + "\t" + str(startB) + "\t" + str(endB) + "\t" + str(lengthB) + "\t" + str(numberB) + "\n")
```

Then you could select random samples from the out file. (If your datasets are large you'll want something more elegant.)